# Passing value from one function to another class function using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, nodes

I am trying to pass value from one page function to another Class function but its not working as expectation

detail.js

```
const {UserData} = require("./userData");

let commonfield="Asia Origin";

var userData= new UserData();
userData.start(commonField);
```

userData.js

```
class UserData extends Commands{
 async start(field){
  console.log(field);
 }
}
```

Here You can see I tried to pass the value but its not passing the value from detail.js to userData.js class function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the wrong function and remove curly braces from `userData`:

```
const UserData = require("./userData");

let commonfield="Asia Origin";

var userData= new UserData();

try {
   const result = await userData.start(commonField); // should be start
} 
catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

```
class UserData extends Commands{
 async start(field){
  console.log(field);
  return field;
 }
}
```

As, `start` is an async function to get its value you need to use await.

You are not exporting the class, you need to do it in order to access it:

```
class UserData extends Commands{
 async start(field){
  console.log(field);
 }
}

export {UserData};
```

Comment: I changed the function name even added your code still not getting the output